# Ubuntu 16.04 How to install rsync server for other systems to access via ssh using cron

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

Setup:  system "prime" with Ubuntu 16.04 and a second hard drive just for backups.

/dev/sdb1 is mounted at /mnt

I created a subdirectory named /mnt/prime for the first backup, of the prime boot SSD contents.

--> Running the command:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --delete --ignore-errors --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /mnt/prime
```

does indeed make a nice mirror copy of the root file system into that directory /mnt/prime

---

So now, in attempting to set up a rsync server for the rest of the Linux systems (Another Ubuntu and a handful of Raspian Jessie systems), I am  following these directions:

[How to Use rsync to Backup Your Data on Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/135533/how-to-use-rsync-to-backup-your-data-on-linux/)

EXCERPT:  it says to enter the following two commands:

```
yum -y install ssh rsync
sudo apt-get install ssh rsync
```

First problem is that there is no yum command on this system, so I skipped that step.  rsync installed with no problems.

All of my systems have done the passwordless login setup

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub prime
```

and I have no problem with passwordless scp copies.

**The question is:** how to I proceed so this system can become a rsync server for other Linux systems.

Comment: Why in the world are you installing yum!? Doesn't `sudo apt-get install ssh rsync` work?

Comment: Yes, that works, so I changed the question to reflect that fact.

Comment: No, you are still using `yum`. Forget `yum`. Ignore any commands involving `yum`. Follow the rest of the tutorial now.

Comment: Roger that, @terdon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. In the Debian world (which includes Ubuntu), packages are installed using `apt` or `apt-get`. This is the system's package manager. You were trying to use a package manager (`yum`) from a different family of distributions, the Red Hat family. This is actually mentioned in the site you linked to:

> On Red Hat distributions, the command is “yum install rsync” and on Debian it is “sudo apt-get install rsync.”

So, instead of this:

```
sudo yum -y install ssh rsync
```

Do this:

```
sudo apt install ssh rsync
```

And forget about `yum`.

Answer (score 1):

If "prime" prompts for a password even after the public key has been installed, then you need to review /etc/ssh/sshd_config and ~/.ssh on "prime".

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

~/.ssh: (check permissions and naming)

```
drwx------  2 [user] [group]   1024 Dec  5  2012 .ssh
-rw-------  1 [user] [group]   5622 May 18  2015 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also check /etc/ssh/ssh_config on "solar" to ensure it references the private key you generated.

Comment: OK.  I don't see anything out of the ordinary, and I can ssh and scp back and forth just fine.

Comment: Ahh - so only rsync is asking for the password... it's being run with sudo and you aren't specifying the base login in the rsync command. - might that be it?

Comment: Yeah, @Larry, I see the right answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/939677/ubuntu-16-04-rsync-via-ssh-prompts-me-for-password-how-to-make-it-a-cron-job  ;-)